# ¿Como obtener value de un input usando jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

La siguiente linea:

```
<a id="asociar-1500" style='color: #004881' href="#" title='Asociar al Proveedor' class="btn btn-danger"><input type="hidden" value = "true"></>
```

Me genera el siguiente HTML:

```
<a id="aosciar" class="btn btn-danger" title="Asociar al Proveedor" href="#" style="color: #004881">
<input type="hidden" value="true">
</a>
```

***Quisiera saber como obtener el Value del Input que esta en Hidden***, para eso estoy probando con esta función jquery:

```
$('a[id^=asociar-]').click(function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

var inputs = (this).getElementsByTagName('input');

console.log(inputs[0]);
var asociado = inputs[0].attr('value');

console.log(asociado);

});
```

Pero no he logrado entrar al input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para obtener el valor (atributo value) de un campo `input` o `select` o `textarea` usa `val()` [Ver documentación jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1) .

```
$('a[id^=asociar-]').click(function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var inputs = $('input');

  var asociado = $(inputs).val();

  console.log(asociado);

});
```

Debes crear un objeto jQuery con el elemento que obtienes en `inputs`, de esta forma podrás usar el método `val()` de jQuery.

Más información sobre los objetos de jQuery en el siguiente enlace (en inglés): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

También podrías hacerlo de esta manera, asumiendo que no necesites la variable inputs después:

```
$('a[id^=asociar-]').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var asociado = $('input[type=hidden]').val();
  console.log(asociado);
});
```

Comment: Recibo este mensaje de error:TypeError: inputs[0].val is not a function
 

var asociado = inputs[0].val();

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciona con el cambio, te importaría explicarme la lógica?

Comment: `var inputs = ` no es un objeto jQuery, al hacer el "wrap" en la siguiente línea estamos creando un objeto jQuery el cual nos permite usar el método val() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese fragmento de html lo tengo dentro de una tabla, el input lo necesito para consultar el estado de una entidad relacionada al row donde se hizo click, pero esa parte ya la tengo resuelta, solo no encontraba como obtener el value de ese input...muchas gracias

Answer (score 9):

No uses `attr` usa [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) en su lugar

```
var asociado = inputs[0].val();// es como un get
```

> Si cambias var inputs = (this).getElementsByTagName('input'); por var
>   inputs =$('input')

**Explicación:**

En este caso `var inputs = (this).getElementsByTagName` `inputs` no es un [objeto de jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), por tanto no tiene ningun metodo asociado de jQuery

En cambio cuando se invoca `inputs =$('input')` se agrega un wrapper que convierte `inputs` a objeto de jQuery y probee a tu objeto de todos los metodos disponibles

Comment: Hola jasilva: recibo un "undefined"

Comment: Si cambias `var inputs = (this).getElementsByTagName('input');` por `var inputs =$('input')`

Comment: Recibo: TypeError: inputs[0].val is not a function
 

var asociado = inputs[0].val();

Comment: Parece que recibes, solo un input, en lugar de un array, asi que invocando `inputs.val();` deberia bastar. Ahora, si quieres que esto solo para este input en particular, te recomendaria que le agregaras un `id` y lo invocaras a traves de su `id` De esta manera `var input =$("#mielemento");`