# Obtener id de usuario logueado en javascript y laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

necesito obtener el ID del usuario loggeado en mi app. Aclaro que nose nada de javascript.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
function guardarToken(token){
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('token',token);
  

    var config = {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"').content

        } 
    }

    axios.post('/token',formData, config).then( respuesta=>{
        console.log(respuesta);
    }).catch( e=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

Necesito obtener el id del usuario loggeado además del token.
en la vista lo obtengo con:

`<input id="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" name="user_id" type="hidden">`

Controller:

```
public function savetoken(Request $request)
{


    
    $this->validate($request, [
        'user_id'     =>  'required',
        'token'  =>  'required',
       ]);

        Notificaciones::create([
          'user_id'  => $request->user_id,
          'token' => $request->token
        ]);
  
        return back()->with('success', 'token saved successfully!');
}
```

**como puedo pasar el id del usuario loggeado=?**

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con el código que muestras?

Comment: Creo que el problema es que el código js no pasa el campo user_id. Nose como hacerlo

Comment: Tendrías que agregarlo al FormData como haces con el token `formData.append('user_id', valorDelInput);`

Comment: También lo puedes obtener en el backend, de todas maners va a ser el mismo que el del front `Notificaciones::create([ 'user_id'  => Auth::id(), 'token' => $request->token ]);`

Comment: Entonces lo paso de la siguiente manera? https://pastebin.com/Mavaj34d corrígeme si esta mal pls

Comment: Tienes que obtener el valor del input para pasárselo al append del formdata

Comment: okey, como hago eso? lo siento es que no se nada de js

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9267/como-obtener-value-de-un-input-usando-jquery#:~:text=Para%20obtener%20el%20valor%20(atributo,var%20asociado%20%3D%20%24(inputs).

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien para que lo quieres es JS, pero si al final lo estas haciendo un POST y realmente lo requieres es para identificar el usuario que guarda, yo te recomendaría obtener el usuario logueado en el controlador y no pedirlo en el request.

```
public function savetoken(Request $request)
{

   $user_id = Auth::id();
    
    $this->validate($request, [
        'token'  =>  'required',
       ]);

        Notificaciones::create([
          'user_id'  => $user_id,
          'token' => $request->token
        ]);
  
        return back()->with('success', 'token saved successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Es que la vista dónde tengo el input tiene su propio controlador. Y me gustaría obtener el user_id desde el input con js. Ya que en el input pienso colocar un valor estático sin usar el ID del usuario loggeado